# method not allowed error while using wcf webinvoke post

Tags: wcf

Hi following is Operation Contract , where im trring to insert some data , so im using WebInvoke POST method, but when im calling this method its giving me an error saying "Method not allowed"

do i have to change any configuration settings for allowing POST calls in web.config?

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(
 UriTemplate = "/Album/PostData?name={name}&CrBy={createdBy}" , 
 Method="POST")]
 void PostUserData(string name, string createdBy);
```

and im calling my service as below

http://localhost:2170/MySampleService.svc/xml/Album/PostData?name=devpost&CrBy=postadmin

Answer (score 2):

Well you should use `Method="GET"` if you want to call your service like this. Also the definition of the method name and arguments don't seem to match your query string.

If you want to use POST verb then you need to send a POST request and you will not be able to invoke the service by directly typing the url in the browser.

Comment: No! Get operations should not modify data. They should be idempotent.

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka, that's correct, I didn't notice that he is trying to modify data.

Comment: "and you will not be able to invoke the service by directly typing the url in the browser" - this just saved me a bunch of time!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add in web.config

1.

```
<endpoint address="customBinding" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicConfig" contract="WcfRest.IService1"/>
```

2.

```
<bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="basicConfig">
          <binaryMessageEncoding/>
          <httpTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method in the interface as

```
public class InputClass
{


public string Name{get;set;}
public string CreatedBy{get;set}
}

    [OperationContract]
     [WebInvoke(
     UriTemplate = "PostUserData" , 
     Method="POST",
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json))]
     void PostUserData(InputClass input);
```

See the link for more info.http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your service from javascript in a browser?

Does the html page reside in the same domain as the wcf service?

If they are **not in the same domain**, then I would say that it is a **cross-site-scripting** issue. I belive GET is allowed cross-sites, but POST are not. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP would be a solution, if it's supported server-side (by WCF)